# How does KNearestNeighborMatching.Match work

Tags: c#, computer-vision, accord.net

I've reviewed the documentation for this method here: http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/M_Accord_Imaging_KNearestNeighborMatching_1_Match_1.htm

The description is rather brief: "Matches two sets of feature points." I've tried it a couple of times, first by using the result of SURFing the same image twice and, second, by SURFing two different images. The first test returned, what I expected, a little less matching points that the points found by SURF. The second got me scratching my head, I got more points than the largest number of points found by SURF. So, obviously, I don't know what to expect from this method. Can anyone give me a more detailed description of what I can expect?

What I am trying to do is to determine how similar two images of different sizes are. You can see a previous, related question I made here: [Accord.NET Comparing two images to determine similarity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073315/accord-net-comparing-two-images-to-determine-similarity)

Answer (score 0):

The method uses a k-Nearest Neighbor classification algorithm to learn a mapping between the descriptors in one image and a vector of integer indices indicating their position. From the [source code of the KNearestNeighborMatch class](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/6c2dfe13664c856660cda535fdea67ff9897ce0b/Sources/Accord.Vision/Accord.Imaging/Matching/KNearestNeighborMatching%601.cs#L233), you can see:

```
/// <summary>
///   Creates a nearest neighbor algorithm with the feature points as
///   inputs and their respective indices a the corresponding output.
/// </summary>
/// 
protected virtual IMulticlassScoreClassifier<T> CreateNeighbors(T[] features)
{
    int[] outputs = Vector.Range(0, features.Length);

    // Create a k-Nearest Neighbor classifier to classify points
    // in the second image to nearest points in the first image
    return new KNearestNeighbors<T>(K, Distance).Learn(features, outputs);
}
```

The point of building this classifier is that now you can pass any descriptor to it, even of those who were not in the original image, and it will give you the index of the descriptor in the original image that is the more closest to it. So in practice, you can use this classifier to obtain the best matches between the feature points from two different images.

Regarding the observation about the number of points returned by the function, this is [explained in lines 144-154](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/6c2dfe13664c856660cda535fdea67ff9897ce0b/Sources/Accord.Vision/Accord.Imaging/Matching/KNearestNeighborMatching%601.cs#L144):

```
 // We should build the classifiers with the highest number
 // of training points. Thus, if we have more points in the
 // second image than in the first, we'll have to swap them

 if (points2.Length > points1.Length)
 {
     var aux = points1;
     points1 = points2;
     points2 = aux;
     swap = true;
 }
```

So as you can see, the method will use as the "anchor" image the image that has the largest number of SURF descriptors. This is needed so no feature point in the image with smaller number of descriptor is left unclassified.

Answering the original question about how to compute a measure of compatibility between two images, a possibility is to consider the total number of point matches, the sum of best scores between the two images, the minimum (worst) score, the best score, or a combination of these (maybe following something along the lines of the [Hausdorff distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_distance)).