# C# Accent K-nearest neighbor function parameter problems

Tags: c#, .net, accord.net

I am trying to use the Accord library's K-nearest neighbor function which can work with any type .

My objective is to use it with Bitmap data, but even when copying the example code and pasting it, I am getting this error:

```
Error   4   The best overloaded method match for 'Accord.MachineLearning.KNearestNeighbors<System.Drawing.Bitmap>.KNearestNeighbors(int, int, System.Drawing.Bitmap[], int[], Accord.Math.Distances.IDistance<System.Drawing.Bitmap>)' has some invalid arguments   D:\...\WindowsFormsApplication1\WidgetControl.cs    295 49  Project_Ochare
```

[image: weird stuff]

It's really odd, because it's exactly as the example. As far as I know the parameters should work.
I have Accord's main, extension core, math, math extensions, math code, machine learning and statistics added as references.

I tried to search, but I couldn't find any answer..

The example code is the same as this: 
http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_MachineLearning_KNearestNeighbors_1.htm

What's wrong?

This is their example code that errors up:

```
private void __Test()
{
    // The k-Nearest Neighbors algorithm can be used with
    // any kind of data. In this example, we will see how
   // it can be used to compare, for example, Strings.

    string[] inputs = 
    {
        "Car",    // class 0
        "Bar",    // class 0
        "Jar",    // class 0
        "Charm",  // class 1
        "Chair"   // class 1
    };
    int[] outputs =
    {
       0, 0, 0,  // First three are from class 0
       1, 1,     // And next two are from class 1
    };

    // Now we will create the K-Nearest Neighbors algorithm. For this
    // example, we will be choosing k = 1. This means that, for a given
    // instance, only its nearest neighbor will be used to cast a new
    // decision. 

    // In order to compare strings, we will be using Levenshtein's string distance
    KNearestNeighbors<string> knn = new KNearestNeighbors<string>(k: 1, classes: 2, inputs: inputs, outputs: outputs, distance: Distance.Levenshtein);

    // After the algorithm has been created, we can use it:
    int answer = knn.Compute("Chars"); // answer should be 1.
}
```

These are the error messages I get. I made a new empty project with only the Accord example code for KNearest.
It wants me to change Distance.Levenshtein to  Distance.Levenshtein(),
then it tells me it needs parameters, no matter how I write it or what I add, it gives the same error.

for example  Distance.Levenshtein("",  ""), Distance.Levenshtein(0,  0)
Distance.Levenshtein("",""), Distance.Levenshtein(new string[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGyFh.jpg), new string[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OGyFh.jpg)), and so on.. anything I could think of trying.

Distance. offers a ton of measurement functions, they all result in the same error.

Error messages:

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'Accord.MachineLearning.KNearestNeighbors<string>.KNearestNeighbors(int, int, string[], int[], Accord.Math.Distances.IDistance<string>)' has some invalid arguments    D:\Dropbox\C#\KNearestTest\KNearestTest\Form1.cs    48  45  KNearestTest


Error   2   Argument 5: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Accord.Math.Distances.IDistance<string>' D:\Dropbox\C#\KNearestTest\KNearestTest\Form1.cs    49  59  KNearestTest
```

Comment: Add the code, but for the error I suspect you're trying to pass a Bitmap to the function and it expects an array of items, if you want to manipulate the pixel data then fix the data with LockBitmap, read the data to a byte array and then use the function with the byte array.

Comment: @Gusman I am not sure if it's related to that. Even with their own examples the error pops up :/

Comment: The error with the example is just because a typo, instead of `Distance.Levenshtein` it should be `Distance.Levenshtein()` as it's a method, not a property.

Comment: @Gusman Ive tried that, and Distance.Levenshtein("","") (because it asks for parameters). Same red underline and message saying there is something wrong :(

Comment: If you get an error add the error message, we have no crystal ball to see what VS is telling you.

Comment: @Gusman Hi, I added the crystal ball to the post

Comment: The crystal ball says you still are using `Distance.Levenshtein` instead of `Distance.Levenshtein("", "")`. Also, instead of trying things without knowing what you do, why not try to read the api help, not just one of the examples?

Comment: @Gusman I really have tried it several ways. The API offers little explanation and only offers this example. That's why I am asking here

Comment: The API examples have finally been updated, so at least now it should be possible to copy & paste the example and make it run without errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the docu doesn't correspond with library. 
I would suggest to write your own implemetation of `IDistance<string>` interface, that uses `Levenschtein` Distance:

```
public class DistanceStringsLevenstein : IDistance<string>
{
    public double Distance(string x, string y)
    {
        return Accord.Math.Distance.Levenshtein(x, y);
    }
}
```

Implementation for Bitmap would be:

```
public class DistanceBitmapLevenstein : IDistance<Bitmap>
{
    public double Distance(Bitmap x, Bitmap y)
    {
        return Accord.Math.Distance.Levenshtein(ImageToByte(x), ImageToByte(y));
    }

    public static byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
    {
        ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
        return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
    }
}
```

After that you cuold use this class in that method:

```
KNearestNeighbors<string> knn = new KNearestNeighbors<string>(k: 1, classes: 2,
        inputs: inputs, outputs: outputs, distance: new DistanceStringsLevenstein());
```

Comment: Thank you!! This works for the example code. How should I implement this for the case of Bitmap?
I tried writing 
    public class DistanceStringsLevenstein : IDistance<Bitmap>
    {
        public double Distance(Bitmap[] x, Bitmap[] y)
        {
            return Accord.Math.Distance.Levenshtein<Bitmap>(x, y);
        }
    }
but it says that this method does not implement interface member Accord.Math.Distances.IDistance<Bitmap, Bitmap>.Distance(Bitmap, Bitmap)

Comment: @MadsM I have updated my answer with Bitmap implementation

Comment: Thank you again. By implementing this, visual studio says "The best overloaded method match for 'Accord.Math.Distance.Levenshtein(string, string)' has some invalid arguments.

Comment: There i  don't know exactly, i would deal with Bitmap as with byte array (see updated answer), but i don't know if it is a right way.

Comment: Thank you for the help. The code works however it returns the same answer every time. Despite the bitmaps being very different. I have validated the input data. I suspect the distance measuring is a bit strange :/

Comment: If all you want to do is to use k-Nearest Neighbors to classify/check similarty of other images, I would recommend not using it with Bitmaps directly but rather with features extracted from those bitmaps. Please take a look at the Bag-of-Visual-Words sample application for an example on how to do this.

Comment: If you really, really want to use KNearestNeighbors<Bitmap>, then you need to define some sort of similarity measure between two bitmaps. [In this question you can find one of such definitions using SURF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073315/accord-net-comparing-two-images-to-determine-similarity), but please note that re-computing SURF features on every distance call is going to be super inefficient. Rather, you can extract all features from all images beforehand and use them in place of the original images.