# can't get KNearestNeighborMatching in Accord.Imaging to build in C#

Tags: c#, image, computer-vision

I want to use SpeededUpRobustFeaturesDetector Class to compare images that may be distorted.
I found a great example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40073315/accord-net-comparing-two-images-to-determine-similarity) but get build error:
"KNearestNeighborMatching COULD NOT BE FOUND" even though I added reference Accord.Imaging 3.8.0.0 in the past and have been using it without problem for other computer vision work.

The Accord online doc. shows KNearestNeighborMatching Class within Accord.Imaging

I tried "Accord.Imaging.KNearestNeighborMatching" but that doesn't work.

Here is my code copied from that link..........................

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;


using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;



using Accord.Video;
using Accord.Video.DirectShow;
using Accord.Imaging;
using Accord.Imaging.Filters;
using ACCORD_WindowsFormsApp9;



namespace ACCORD_WindowsFormsApp9
{
    class Computer_Vision
    {





public class ProcessImage
{
    public static void Similarity(System.IO.Stream model, System.IO.Stream observed,
        out float similPercent)
    {
        Bitmap bitModel = new Bitmap(model);
        Bitmap bitObserved = new Bitmap(observed);

        // For method Difference, see http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/673023f7-799a-2ef6-7933-31ef09974dde.htm

        // Inspiration for this process: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHT46f2244E
        // Greyscale class http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/html/d7196dc6-8176-4344-a505-e7ade35c1741.htm
        // Convert model and observed to greyscale
        Grayscale filter = new Grayscale(0.2125, 0.7154, 0.0721);
        // apply the filter to the model
        Bitmap greyModel = filter.Apply(bitModel);
        // Apply the filter to the observed image
        Bitmap greyObserved = filter.Apply(bitObserved);
        int modelPoints = 0, matchingPoints = 0;

        /*
         * This doesn't work. Images can have different sizes
        // For an example, https://thecsharper.com/?p=94
        // Match
        var tm = new ExhaustiveTemplateMatching(similarityThreshold); 
        // Process the images
        var results = tm.ProcessImage(greyModel, greyObserved);
        */

        using (SpeededUpRobustFeaturesDetector detector = new SpeededUpRobustFeaturesDetector())
        {
            List<SpeededUpRobustFeaturePoint> surfModel = detector.ProcessImage(greyModel);
            modelPoints = surfModel.Count();
          List<SpeededUpRobustFeaturePoint> surfObserved = detector.ProcessImage(greyObserved);

            KNearestNeighborMatching matcher = new KNearestNeighborMatching(5);
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  "COULD NOT BE FOUND"  
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

            var results = matcher.Match(surfModel, surfObserved);
            matchingPoints = results.Length;
        }
        // Determine if they represent the same points
        // Obtain the pairs of associated points, we determine the homography matching all these pairs


        // Compare the results, 0 indicates no match so return false
        if (matchingPoints <= 0)
        {
            similPercent = 0.0f;
        }

        similPercent = (matchingPoints * 100) / modelPoints;
    }
}
```

Comment: I hope it's not your phantom "namespace ACCORD_WindowsFormsApp9
{
    class Computer_Vision
    {" floating around up there ;)

Comment: I don't think so.  I've tried deleting it, and replacing it with "namespace Accord.imaging".  Build still cannot find KNearestNeighborMatching.  (And ACCORD_WindowsFormsApp9  was just the project name.)

Comment: Was more referring to the nested class thing you had going on there. But glad it's fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it: The C# project had become corrupt: reference Accord.Vision was   gone and could not be added.

Just had to create a new VS C# forms project, pop in the old .cs files, and re-add all the NuGet Accord libs.  All builds now, especially KNearestNeighborMatching .